# Can someone explain to me why entering numbers[-1][-1][-1] would return x?

Tags: python

This is the list I typed in:

```py
numbers =  [[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three'],[4,'four'],[6,'six']]
```

I’m lost on why `numbers[-1][-1][-1]` would return `'x'`.

Comment: You could have easily answered this for yourself by printing `numbers[-1]` and then `numbers[-1][-1]`.

Answer (score 9):

This is because the first `[-1]` gets the last element in the list `[[1,'one'],[2,'two],[3,'three'],[4,'four'],[6,'six']]`, which is `[6, 'six']`.

Then, the second `[-1]` gets the last element in that list, which is `six`.

Finally, the third `[-1]` returns the last character in the string `six`, which is `x`.

The square brackets (`[]`) tell python to get something at an index, and `-1` is the last one. Strings can be thought of as lists of characters, which is why the `x` is return from that string.

Answer (score 2):

-1 index, means the last element of a list. that you can see

```
e0 = in_nums[-1] # [6, 'six']
e1 = e0[-1] # 'six'
e2 = e1[-1] # 'x'
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you acess the -1 element on a list or a string, you are actually acessing the item on the last index of that list (or str). That said, we have:

```
numbers[-1] -> [6, 'six']    # returns the last element (a list)
numbers[-1][-1] -> 'six'     # returns the last element of the above list
numbers[-1][-1][-1] -> 'x'   # returns the last element of the above str
```